# What does <form action = ""> mean ? Many videos I saw assign the action attribute an empty string and I have no idea what it means

Tags: html, forms, django-forms

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

What will happen after I click the Submit button?

Comment: It will likely post to the page itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Syntax**

```
<form action="URL">
```

the URL shows Where to send the form-data when the form is submitted.

**Example**

On submit, send the form-data to a file named "process_input.php" (to process the input):

```
<form action="/process_input.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
</form>
```

read more: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp